# copying and pasting dynamic data set

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask for a help. I want to create a validation tool for my colleagues. They manually check the audience profile (which is divided on Primary and secondary market - as shown in the picture below). Previously I did similar tool for the different document and it was working fine. I used the names of headers to track the data and when the header was spotted then Excel copied the whole data set - until the last row with data. However, the problem here is the header names. In the previous document names were unique. Here as you can see headers are the same for both Primary and Secondary market. What code should I use, to copy the whole Primary Market data set and Secondary Market data set to separate sheets (so in this example to get data from A9:D18 and then A20:D29). They consist of different values each time but they will always have the space in between. Could anyone help me with this?

[image]